# What is the link between the queries Bayesian Networks can answer, and inference algorithms?

Tags: bayesian, inference, causality, bayesian-network, approximate-inference

I have seen two concepts linked to Bayesian Networks:

1. Bayesian Networks can answer different **types of queries**. These types include proof of evidence, most probable explanation, computing maximum a posteriori.
2. There are **Inference Algorithms** used to compute the probability of some events. These algorithms can be exact or approximate. Exact algorithms include algorithms like Inference by Variable Elimination, Junction Tree, Conditioning based inference. Approximate algorithms include variational methods, sampling-based methods, loopy belief propagation.

My question: **what is the link between these queries and inference algorithms? Are inference algorithms used to answer these queries?**